# Trying to export DF and getting this error: unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'

Tags: r

I am trying to do a simple export of a data frame.  Here is my code:

```
write.table(df1, "C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/data_dump.txt", sep=",")
```

When I run that, I get the following error:

```
Error in write.table(df, "C:/Users/ryans/OneDrive/Desktop/data_dump.txt",  : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

This comes from a 5x33 tibble:

```
url   priority raw_subject via   generated_times~ recipient group_id tags     id
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>       <lis>            <int> <chr>        <int> <lis> <int>
1 http~ normal   Welcome to~ <lis~       15369 NA              NA <chr~    24
```

I captured that tibble as a df and converted that into: `df1<-data.frame(df)`

I think the problem comes from a field named 'custom_field', but I'm not completely sure.  Anyway, some of the data in that field looks like this:

```
num raw_title   url raw_title_in_portal removable   id  system_field_options    raw_description editable_in_portal  position    _sdc_table_version  tag updated_at  required_in_portal  _sdc_received_at    title_in_portal _sdc_sequence   title   required    custom_field_options    type    created_at  active  sub_type_id _sdc_batched_at collapsed_for_agents    regexp_for_validation   description agent_description   visible_in_portal
19  Dataset Type    https:///3600.json  Dataset Type    TRUE    3600    []      FALSE   12  0       9/13/2018 22:50 FALSE   03:10.4 Dataset Type    15373945    Dataset Type    FALSE   [{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Public', 'raw_name': 'Public', 'value': 'public'}, {'id': 3600, 'default': False, 'name': 'Private', 'raw_name': 'Private', 'value': 'private'}]  tagger  9/13/2018 21:49 FALSE       03:19.3 FALSE               FALSE
20  Type of Dataset https:///3600.json  Type of Dataset TRUE    3600    []      FALSE   14  0       9/13/2018 22:50 FALSE   03:10.4 Type of Dataset 15373   Type of Dataset FALSE   [{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Public', 'raw_name': 'Public', 'value': 'public'}, {'id': 3600, 'default': False, 'name': 'Private', 'raw_name': 'Private', 'value': 'private'}]  tagger  9/13/2018 21:40 TRUE        03:19.3 FALSE           Type of Dataset FALSE
21  Type of Dataset https:///3600.json  Type of Dataset TRUE    3600    []      FALSE   14  0       9/19/2018 23:36 FALSE   58:29.3 Type of Dataset 15373   Type of Dataset FALSE   [{'id': 36001, 'default': False, 'name': 'Public', 'raw_name': 'Public', 'value': 'public'}, {'id': 3600, 'default': False, 'name': 'Private', 'raw_name': 'Private', 'value': 'private'}]  tagger  9/13/2018 21:40 TRUE        59:50.2 FALSE           Public or Private dataset?  FALSE
```

I think the problem stems from a field named 'custom_field_options'.  That's my guess.  I think the whole data frame, or at least that one field (custom_field_options) needs to be coerced...somehow.  I thought converting everything to `data.frame()` would fix the problem, but apparently not, or it's a different problem.  How can I get this field parsed correctly so I can get the data exported?

Comment: Please edit your post to include representative & minimal sample data using `dput`. It seems your `data.frame` contains nested `list`s (columns `tags` and `via`?).

Comment: The most common place to encounter this sort of problem is with dataframes that contain objects of class `POSIXlt`. For that reason, most people adhere to a rule of not using lists as columns in dataframes. You should do a search on the error message: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=unimplemented%20type%20%27list%27%20in%20%27EncodeElement%27